# How to expand a json column in excel with python using pandas

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, excel, pandas

I'm trying to convert json file to excel automatically by using pandas and python
This is my code

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('orders.json', encoding='utf8') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)


pd.json_normalize(data["orders"])
df.to_excel('exported_json_data.xlsx')
```

This is the json file

```
{
    "orders": [
        {
            "date": "22.07",
            "name": "Moses Shif",
            "phone": "166666666",
            "book": [
                "heart stones"
            ]
        },
        {
            "date": "22.07",
            "name": "Jake Mashro",
            "phone": "1555555555",
            "book": [
                "the witcher",
                "harry potter"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

What the output is:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKYuM.png)

What output I'm trying to get:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLvif.png)

I've tried to

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data["orders"], "book")
```

But it only gives me:
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3a4N.png)
Without dates, names and phones

**I found the solution! Thanks to [BENY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64251052/14933011)**

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('orders.json', encoding='utf8') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)


df = pd.json_normalize(data)

s = df.explode('book')
out = pd.DataFrame(s.book.tolist())

s.to_excel('exported_json_data.xlsx')
```

I also removed the orders from the json file so it looks like:

```
[
    {
        "date": "22.07",
        "name": "Moses Shif",
        "phone": "166666666",
        "book": [
            "heart stones"
        ]
    },
    {
        "date": "22.07",
        "name": "Jake Mashro",
        "phone": "155555555",
        "book": [
            "the witcher",
            "harry potter"
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample orders file

```
{
    "orders": [
        {
            "date": "22.07",
            "name": "Moses Shif",
            "phone": "166666666",
            "book": [
                "heart stones"
            ]
        },
        {
            "date": "22.07",
            "name": "Jake Mashro",
            "phone": "1555555555",
            "book": [
                "the witcher",
                "harry potter"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I believe, you are looking for [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('orders.json', encoding='utf8') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)


df = pd.json_normalize(data["orders"])
df = df.explode("book")
df.to_excel('exported_json_data.xlsx')
```

[image]